# Error retrieving a dependency from MavenCentral()

Tags: kotlin, gradle, maven-central

I am facing an error dowloading junit from mavenCentral.

The error:

```
> Could not find method testImplementation() for arguments [org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Of course I have already checked and the dependency exists in maven central repository.
The build gradle file is quite easy and I am using a gradle wrapper.

build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.3'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Any idea what to check?

Comment: Per the https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.9.3 link it shows this as the proper syntax to list it as a dependency `testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3")`

Comment: @CAMD_3441 already tested this syntax too and I have the same error

Answer (score 0):

`testImplementation` is a configuration that is added by a plugin.
But you do not have any plugins applied.
If you for example apply the `java` plugin, or `java-application` plugin, or `groovy` plugin, or `application` plugin, ..., the configuration is added and can be used to define dependencies.